# vector of ofstream* cannot open any element

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream

In my project, I am trying to create a set of files for output. However, I am unable to open any of the ofstreams whenever I try to approach this. My best approach would use a vector of ofstream pointers shown below, but I am unable to open any of them.

```
        vector<ofstream*> out;
        for (int m = 0; m < p; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < p; n++)
            {
                string outname = "TLR" + to_string(n) + "|" + to_string(m) + ".txt";
                out.push_back(new ofstream{ outname.c_str() });
            }
        }
```

p is typically 5. is_open() reveals that nothing opens (duh). My program compiles and runs with no output. perror says "invalid argument." I am on visual studio 2013 running windows 10. What can I do to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have pipe character "|" in the outname?

Comment: @KIIV so that I know what "m" and "n" are--they are ints, so I need to separate them with something

Comment: On windows | seems to be a forbidden character for file name or directory. Try underscore instead

Comment: I suspect that @KIIV is hinting that a pipe character is probably not a valid character in a filename. After all, in a shell command it's a pipe.

Comment: Any special reason for pointers? You can store `std::ofstream` by value and use `out.emplace_back(outname);`

Answer (score 5):

The `|` character is not allowed in filenames on Windows.  The `?`,`:`,`<`,`>`, `\`, `/`, `*`, and `"` characters are also not allowed.  All other printable unicode characters are valid.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't think you don't want to create a vector of ofstream objects. What you instead want to do is create a vector of strings for file names, and write to each one using one ofstream object. What I'm imagining is something like this:

```
vector<string> out;
for (int m = 0; m < p; m++)
    for (int n = 0; n < p; n++)
        out.push_back("TLR" + to_string(n) + "_" + to_string(m)+ ".txt");

// Then iterate over the files writing to each one whatever you'd like with the ofstream
```

Also, like people have been commenting above, the "|" character is reserved and cannot be used in a file name